# Pip install from a specific commit prompts "requirements already satisfied"

Tags: python, git, pip, virtualenv, requirements.txt

I'm using `pip` and a `requirements.txt` file to handle my python packages in my virtualenv. I have a particular package I install from Github so that inside my file I have:

```
git+ssh://git@github.com/myuser/mypackage.git#egg=mypackage
```

Since I'm working on the package quite often I need to re-install it but:
`pip install -r requirements.txt` gives me back

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade)...
```

for all the packages in requirements.txt that have new versions.

If I run `pip install -r requirements.txt --upgrade` it tries to upgrade **all** my packages (that I do **NOT** want) but I want to upgrade only `mypackage`. In requirements.txt I've tried to add a specific commit, like so:

```
git+ssh://git@github.com/myuser/mypackage.git@733c5b616da27cba14478c24b#egg=mypackage
```

But when I run pip again it throws:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade)..bla bla bla
```

**QUESTION:**

- Is there a way to upgrade **only** the specific package `mypackage` possibily using the requirements.txt file?
- Do I need to specify the `#egg=mypackage`?

Comment: I have found the option [non-recursive upgrade](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide.html#non-recursive-upgrades) but how to use it with a `requirements.txt` file?

Comment: Unless you are adding requirements, you already have them all installed, so you don't need to specify it. when you do add a new requirement, you can just install it manually, as it will not happen frequently.

Comment: I don't add new requirements, I need to upgrade only `mypackage` all the time because it changes quite often. Specifying a specific commit doesn't help

Comment: `pip install -U --no-deps git-ssh@...`

Comment: @Davidmh yes..how to specify this in the `requirements.txt` so that I can upgrade only for `mypackage` for that specific commit? I need to track in the file the version I am using

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason you're getting `Requirement already satisfied` is because if you do not pass `--upgrade` or `-U` (the shorthand), the package is not modified if it is already installed.

(This part of the command has had a *lot* of discussion. Check out the first 4 issues [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues?q=upgrade+sort%3Acomments-desc))

---

*Is there a way to upgrade only the specific package `mypackage` possibily using the requirements.txt file?*

You need to specify just `mypackage` to pip when telling it to upgrade. If you wanted to update only requests, the pip command is:

```
pip install --upgrade requests
```

Similarly, to update from your git repository, you want to do:

```
pip install --upgrade git+ssh://git@github.com/myuser/mypackage.git#egg=mypackage
```

Since it's a URL is a long thing, what I suggest you do what @daphtdazz suggests, use multiple requirements files, as follows:

requirements.txt

```
requests~=2.12.3
simplejson~=3.10.0
-r git_requirements.txt
```

git_requirements.txt

```
git+ssh://git@github.com/myuser/mypackage.git#egg=mypackage
```

Additionally, I suggest you use shell-aliases for your shell to ease the typing load.

```
alias pip_git_upgrade="pip install --upgrade -r git_requirements.txt"
```

---

*Do I need to specify the `#egg=mypackage`?*

To quote from [pip's official documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#working-out-the-name-and-version):

> Any URL may use the #egg=name syntax to explicitly state the project name.

Basically, using `#egg=mypackage` is a good idea since you are making the the project name explicit.

Answer (score 2):

If you have dependencies that need to be at a particular version, then you should fix them in your requirements file to stay at that version. So for example (although not realistic):

```
mock~=2.0.0
pexpect==2.4.1
git+ssh://git@github.com/myuser/mypackage.git@733c5b616da27cba14478c24b#egg=mypackage
```

- `mock` will be updated to any version that looks like 2.0.* (normally changes in the most minor number are bugfixes, so you generally want this)
- `pexpect` will be fixed at 2.4.1
- `mypackage` will always be updated whenever possible.

If you only want to upgrade a single package though, then just upgrade that one:

```
pip install -U git+ssh://git@github.com/myuser/mypackage.git
```

Another alternative if you want to upgrade all of them regularly but some more regularly than others would be to split up the requirements file. See [the pip docs](https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install/#requirements-file-format). I suspect this needs an up to date version of `pip` and `setuptools` (but you're updating those regularly anyway, right??).

For example, you could then have:

#### update_regularly_reqs.txt

```
git+ssh://git@github.com/myuser/mypackage.git@733c5b616da27cba14478c24b#egg=mypackage
```

#### all_requirements.txt

```
-r update_regularly_reqs.txt
mock~=2.0.0
pexpect==2.4.1
```

### Edit to add info on `#egg=`

The `#egg=mypackage` bit is required if you want to check it out using pip and also edit the code in that package, but then you need to use:

```
-e git+ssh://...#egg=mypackage
```

`pip` will then make a directory in the `src` directory in your virtualenv's home directory (use `cdvirtualenv` to find it) with that name, or at least it did on my system, and will check out the code using `git clone` (or appropriate for Mercurial or SVN if using those) so you can go and edit it in place.

But if you don't specify `-e` (as you did) then I think it checks it out as a normal package, which makes it harder for you to manage if you want to edit it in place, and then you don't need the `#egg=` bit.

No doubt there are lots of config options too... a good place to start is that doc I linked.

Comment: No, not in my case. Especially the github portion, changing the commit hash in the `requirements.txt` and running again `pip install -r requirements.txt` will not upgrade my package from github, no matter what I put after the @ a commit, a branch a tag. It will stick with the current version

Comment: You always need to pass `-U` or `--upgrade` if you want to change what is already installed. I think you should be using the `-e` option though. You should always be able just to upgrade the single package using `pip install -U git+ssh://git@github.com/myuser/mypackage.git`; I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: You've linked to (outdated) pip 1.1 docs... pip 9.0.1 recently released.